# Reject Record Save Without Throwing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm running Rails 5.2. I have a `Cart` and `Item` model and I want to combine the quantities and totals of duplicate `items` that are added to the cart.

My `Cart` accepts nested attributes for `Item` and I originally thought about using the `reject_if` condition to prevent the save of the "duplicate" `item`. However, I need to actually do this from the model since I have other scripts that can create a cart and items without submitting form data to the controller. From a callback in my `Item` model, how can I reject the save like I would with `reject_if`?

My original idea which I have abandoned:

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :items
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes.function_that_decides_to_reject_or_not }
end
```

What I would like to achieve:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :cart
    before_save :combine_and_reject

    def combine_and_reject
        #pseudo-code
        #if self.sku == to other items' sku in cart
            #combine the quantities and reject self silently. 
        #end
    end
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I miss something but I don't understand why you want to handle this within your model. I would recommend you to calculate this "on the fly" when you display your `Cart`. Imagine the following code:

```rb
#carts controller

def show
  skus = @cart.items.pluck(:sku)
  # ['678TYU', '678TYU', 'POPO90']
  skus.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |sku,counts| counts[sky] += 1 }
  # {"678TYU"=>2, "POPO90"=>1}
end
```

In this way each time you want to display your cart you can handle quantities depending of your duplicates.

Duplicates in your cart are not an issue, because in real life you can have two chocolate bar in your cart. It's only on your receipt where the duplicates disappears.

Comment: So my cart page has a field to update the quantity. If a user selected a new quantity then one of the two parts would be updated with too many items in the quantity. So somewhere server side I still have to alleviate this issue.

Comment: Not sure to get it...but if the user click somewhere to increase the quantity just do a call to `create` a new item or to destroy `one`.

Comment: I see what you're saying and yes it would work but I need to be able to create one item with its respective quantity rather than x items for quantity x. Otherwise, I would have to write a bunch of ugly js to create and delete html elements to make this work with nested attributes since the `Cart` drives all the callbacks & validations each time a child is updated.